# Cannot connect to SQL Server Compact from C#

Tags: c#, sql

I am brand new to Visual C#. (I come from javaland)

I used the IDE's `Data -> Add New Data Source` tool to create a database my app can connect to.
I can open the database from the IDE's Database Explorer, but I can't connect to the database from
the app.

The database is a SQL Server Compact 3.5 file with no password or encryption. This is the auto generated connection string:

```
Data Source=|DataDirectory|\test.sdf
```

but when I run the following code ...

```
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\test.sdf");
  con.Open();
```

I get the error

> A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL
>   Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)

at `con.Open()`;

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using the [`SqlCeConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection(v=vs.100).aspx) class, not `SqlConnection`. You may have to add a reference to the system.data.sqlserverce assembly. The `SqlConnection` class is used to connect to a full version of SQL Server (including Express).